# Generalize rest service calls and map server response to my object

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to create a generic rest service to be used in all my services, for example for **POST** request I have this code

```
post<T>(relativeUrl: string, body?: any,  params?: HttpParams, headers?: HttpHeaders): Observable<HttpResponse<T>> {
        return this.executeRequest(this.createRequest(relativeUrl, body, params, headers, 'POST'))
    }
```

and in similar manner for other HTTP request methods. All this methods call *createRequest* and *executeRequest*

```
// TODO: Finish and check arguments
    private createRequest(relativeUrl: string, body: any, params: HttpParams | null, headers: HttpHeaders | null, method: string ): HttpRequest<any> {

        let url: string;
        if (relativeUrl.startsWith('http') || relativeUrl.startsWith('https')) {
            url = relativeUrl;
        } else {
            url = `${environment.restUrl}/${relativeUrl}`;
        }


        headers = headers || new HttpHeaders()
        //TODO: If user is logged add Authorization bearer in headers

        return new HttpRequest(method, url, body, {
            headers: headers,
            params: params
        })
    }

    private executeRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
        return <any> this.http.request(request)
            .pipe(
                catchError(error => {
                    return throwError(error);
                })
            );
    }
```

Is this correct as I set the methods?
It's correct the returned value of HTTP request methods? For example in my login.service I use the POST methods in this manner

```
login<User>(email: string, password: string): Observable<HttpResponse<User>>{

        const data = {
            email: email,
            password: password
        };

        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'it'
        })

        return this.restService.post<User>(this.baseUrl, data, null, headers)
            .pipe(
                catchError(error => {
                    this.notificationService.error(error.error.error.message);
                    return throwError(error);
                })
            );
    }
```

I've some doubts on when it happens the conversion from the json returned from the server and my User object. I should made the conversion here in the service or in the component when I use my *loginService* ? How I made this conversion? It's correct

```
Object.assign(new User(), serverResponse.body)
```

?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into *interceptors* if you need to apply logic to every request. Also note that a URL that starts with https *also* starts with http.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Answer (score 1):

the correct way of applying same logic to all your requests is to use Http Interceptors.

Damien Bod has great example for this purpose in his angular-auth-oidc-client library

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let requestToForward = req;

        if (this.oidcSecurityService === undefined) {
            this.oidcSecurityService = this.injector.get(OidcSecurityService);
        }
        if (this.oidcSecurityService !== undefined) {
            let token = this.oidcSecurityService.getToken();
            if (token !== '') {
                let tokenValue = 'Bearer ' + token;
                requestToForward = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: tokenValue } });
            }
        } else {
            console.debug('OidcSecurityService undefined: NO auth header!');
        }

        return next.handle(requestToForward);
    }
}
```

ref:https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client